# Solving number of distinct elements in $O(\frac{n\ell}{p})$ space complexity with $2p$ passes over data

Tags: space-complexity, streaming-algorithm, big-data

Suppose there is an n-element stream with elements from $\{0,1\}^\ell$ which means each element is in set $\{0, \dots , 2^\ell-1\}$. Also may assume $2^\ell >n^2$. How can I with $2p$ passes over the data (for $p \in \{1, \dots , 2^\ell\} $) solve the *number of distinct elements* problem using only $O(\frac{n}{p}\ell)$ bits of memory? Not looking for probabilistic algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the following lines. Preform $p$ iterations where each iteration consists of two passes over the stream. The $i$'th iteration first pass remembers all elements whose index $\bmod p$ equals $i$ , denote this collection by $S_i$. The second pass, for each element of the stream whose index $\bmod p$ is greater than $i$, checks if it appears in $S_i$, and if so deletes it. Denote by $S_i'$ the remaining subset after the second pass, then your algorithm returns $\sum\limits_{i=1}^p |S_i'|$.

Comment: thanks but it **do not work**. at last round there is no $index \mod p$ which is greater thatn $i$. consider case when $p=2$ at last round (second iteration)$i=1$ and we are looking for elements which $index \mod 2 > 1$.

Comment: This just means that $|S_{p-1}'|=|S_{p-1}|$ (we want to count all the unique elements whose index mod $p$ is $p-1$, since they were not counted in any earlier iteration).

Comment: by "remembers all elements" you meant all **non-duplicate** (unique)elements ?

Comment: No, I meant keep all elements in memory (which you can do, as there are $n/p$ of those). After each iteration you only keep the size of $|S_i|'$, so you can reuse memory in the next iteration. To compute the size of $S_i$' you will have to find duplicates, luckily this doesn't require further information from the stream.

Comment: am i doing this right ? for stream $\{1,1,2,1,1,2,3\}$ at iteration one we have $S_0=\{1,2,1,3\}$ and $S'_0 = \{3\}$. for second iteration $S_1=\{1,1,2\}$ and $S'_1 = \{1,1,2\}$.

Comment: Yes, seems about right, $|S_0'|=1$ and $|S_1'|=2$ and you get the number of unique elements.